# how to allow a plugin to store data

Tags: .net, database, plugins

I plan to propose an application which allow developers to provide plugins for it.

In my scenario, plugins access the application data and methods through a web-services layer, and as a consequence, the developer can expect to store his plugin-data using this layer. We do not want to allow database modification for each plugin which would need it or even provide a direct access to the database.

The question is, do you know, or can you imagine, a system that would suit the need of allowing any kind of data to be store in our database in this context ?

The application is an ASP.NET application, database is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a nosql-database then the problem goes away as there is no database-schema to change, all you would have to manage is to make sure that plugins don't mess up eachothers data, some nosql-databases to look at can be found here: [What NoSQL solutions are out there for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the amount of data how about storing XML and passing that back and forth. Each plugin has a row in the database and a field for the XML allowing each plugin to control the data they need to store.

You would also be able to set up a web service which allows chunks of data to be returned based on a web service that receives xpath queries and returns the resultant data. If you have SQL Server 2005 or 2008 you would even be able to submit these queries directly into the sql server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(v=sql.90).aspx

If you want something more lightweight perhaps a json array?

Failing that maybe a key value pair collection for each plugin, essentially allowing them to load and save a dictionary

Comment: wouldn't it be a problem on a large amount of data ?

Comment: Possibly but you haven't specified the type of data, how much data or a structure so I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Is the data common for all the plugins? if so, why would a plugin need to modify the schema? if not, why not have each plugin host their own database a-la SQLite ? then they would be independent of eachother and you wouldn't even need to provide services for storage as the plugins would manage themselves.